# Платформа для создания 2d игр

Tags: c#, разработка-игр

В качестве эксперимента и просто самообучения хотел бы попробовать написать простой 2D платформер. Вряд ли я углублюсь в его разработку, но просто попробовать что да как мне интересно.

Порекомендуйте на чём всё это можно построить, желательно на языке C#, и если не сложно материалы по этому делу.

P.S. можно уже готовые движки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте Unity. B добавок могу посоветовать уроки по нему, тут с нуля создается марио в 2D, а потом еще и в 3D [ссылка](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwalkerboystudio.com%2Fhtml%2Funity_course_lab_4.html&ei=CjghU6GmKuzQ4QSro4GYBw&usg=AFQjCNGtIEMHoprTYCmQvRjHiHe68HS8-Q&sig2=DAR1x7o5gI2tu35S7TcEXg&bvm=bv.62922401,d.bGE&cad=rjt)

Comment: так же куча моделей и исходников программ доступно у них в магазине, есть как бесплатные, так и платные

Comment: что-то я такое читал что в Unity 4.3 добавили всякие плюшки для удобства разработки 2D игр. Что-то там по работе со спрайтами и анимацией. В этих уроках этого нет. Но как бы не беда. Спасибо, сейчас гляну.

Comment: @artemiy, что можете сказать насчёт XNA или других альтернатив ?

Comment: @Пандакун, к сожалению, я не работал с другими движками

Comment: кстати, на счет поддержки 2D в версии 4.3, у них есть приложение (разновидность игры worms вроде как) для демнострации, даны все исходники и функционал у него не маленький. Враги, оружие, бонусы, всё что нужно для платформера.